# RNG giving same number after second interation in loop

Tags: random, colors, c++-cli, backcolor

So, I'm trying to make a game that requires randomly colored pictureboxes. I've been trying to make the random color generator, but I'm running into an issue that I can't explain.

When this code runs (inside of Form1_Load event):

```
for(int i=0; i<6, i++)
{
    DateTime moment = DateTime::Now;
    Random^RNG=gcnew Random(moment.Millisecond);
    color[i]=RNG->Next(16);

    if(color[i]<=9)
    {
        colorStr[i]=color[i].ToString();
    }
    else if(color[i]==10)
    {
        colorStr[i]="A";
    }
    else if(color[i]==11)
    {
        colorStr[i]="B";
    }
    else if(color[i]==12)
    {
        colorStr[i]="C";
    }
    else if(color[i]==13)
    {
        colorStr[i]="D";
    }
    else if(color[i]==14)
    {
        colorStr[i]="E";
    }
    else if(color[i]==15)
    {
        colorStr[i]="F";
    }
    FullColor+=colorStr[i]; //FullColor was initialized with a value of "#";
}

this->textBox1->Text=FullColor;
this->Player->BackColor = System::Drawing::ColorTranslator::FromHTML(FullColor);
```

The textbox displays either all the same number (i.e. #000000), or the first number will be unique, but the other five will be equal to each other (i.e. #A22222).

Comment: Your gigantic if-else chain can be replaced with a simple conversion from a number to a hex string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Random` generator should not be re-created every time. Try to do it once, before the loop:

```
Random^RNG=gcnew Random(moment.Millisecond);
for(int i=0; i<6, i++)
{
    ....
```

(In your case, it seems that the `moment.Millisecond` is the same for sequential calls. But even if it would be different, the generator is not supposed to be re-created.)

---

Instead of the loop, you may consider the following code:

```
Random^ RNG = gcnew Random(); // somewhere at the beginning
....
int color = RNG->Next(0x1000000);
String^ colorStr = color.ToString("X6");
```

Comment: @TheMohawkNinja It could be that you do not need the entire loop and manual `10->A` formatting. I updated the post with a proposal.